# Can I use aluminum foil for a heat gun as a nozzle?

Tags: soldering

Wanted to desolder a small chip with 48 pins on a PCB.

Since my heat gun didn't come with a small nozzle included, can I use aluminum foil to create a ghetto nozzle for it?

What can I do as an alternative option?

Comment: Maybe.  You might be better using the foil as a *shield* for other things.  Nozzles on proper reflow tools aren't used alone but rather in conjunction with turning down the source airflow rate, your improvisation would likely speed up the airflow and increase the chance of blowing small parts right off the board.  Consider getting a rework hot air tool; they're quite cheap now and very handy.  You can of course still damage assorted plastic components but are much less likely to inadvertently displace or roast other electrical components than you are with a heat gun.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use aluminum as the nozzle, even though it's melting point temperature is low, I think aluminum alloy covers the upper limit temperature a chip can bear.

But why your heat gun has no nozzle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You just need to secure it well and play around til you get a good size nozzle at the end with the airspeed you like. If its blowing too hard you could try cutting some vents in the side to take away some of the pressure.

Like the user in the comments said, it may work better to just shield the rest and use the heat gun as is if its just a one off type thing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a nozzle, I  occasionally reflow solder with it off (if I'm doing a panel by hand, for instance, and want to spend less time waiting for my board to heat up between component placements). The main problem is that without one you'll spread heat over a wider area, so you might accidentally shift or desolder components if you're not careful. If you're using an actual heat gun, you might risk high temperatures that could burn your solder mask (although I've used them sucessfully in a pinch).

I do recommend getting a real, temperature controlled rework tool if you're going to be doing more of this in the future but a heat gun with no nozzle should be fine for a one off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well it will work, but you need to consider that aluminium has rather low melting point temperature(660.32 °C). You probably wont have that temperature near PCB, but temperature will be higher near heat gun.